# Custom activity-activity transition

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm developing an android application where i need custom animation for transition between activities which must look something like  [this](http://www.zehfernandes.com/jquery.fullContent/#home)

I checked out  [this](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343)  but not able figure out how to solve my problem

Thanks in advance to any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can solve it by ViewPager as it won't provide you possibility to actually change Activities. 
I guess you need to call

```
overridePendingTransition(int enterAnimation, int exitAnimation)
```

after startActivity and finish methods, and where you define these two animations within xml files in /res/anim folder.

I posted full snippets on my blog so check it, hope it helps a bit - [Custom Animation while switching between Activities](http://quodev.wordpress.com/2013/12/21/custom-animation-while-switching-between-activities/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website you just referenced it seems similar to a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). ViewPager lets you flip from one page to another (this happens on the same activity by the way).